# Best architecture to propagate flutter state change from the bottom up?

Tags: flutter, state

I have a catalog (main page) that displays ads thumbnail, by taping on it, user is pushed a detail view from which it can tap on a message button which pushes the message screen. This message screen requires on some circonstances to be signed in: therefore it might display a button that pushes the sign in screen.

Overall here is the hierarchy:

```
catalogue -> ad detail view -> message screen -> sign in screen.
```

My use case is that when the user successfully signs in, I need to update the message screen.

I can propagate a 'onUpdate' callback down the tree but I am questioning that method.

Does Flutter offer a generic or better way to propagate state changes from the bottom up?

Comment: I would recommend `ChangeNotifierProvider` and `Consumer`, see [this guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). But there are other state management approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Using Global Variables for the State of the Button or
2. Using Provider

Personally for small Apps I use global Variables but as soon as it gets more complicated you should consider Provider.